# Mongodb error after db repair command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongo-repair

I was working with MongoDB using Pymongo Libraries. Suddenly MongoDB stopped. I restarted it. After a while it stopped again. So I searched and tried the following repair command:

```
mongod --dbpath f:/data/db --repair
```

The process kept running. But I stopped it using the keyboard interruption.
Now When I am trying to use start the server using my configuration, the window is getting flashed on my screen.
I do not understand what might be the problem as I could see anything in my log file.

Here are the trace log:https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/0c6538a0124112f253c7f8e70bdde15e
Kindly, let me know what I can do so that I can start and get my data again. I have GBs of data on MongoDB, and month of hardwork will be wasted if not getting started. Please let me know the solution, if any.

My mongoDB is on the Windows 8 server.

Answer (score 1):

OK.. You have managed to get your self in middle of mess. As it says:

> UnsupportedFormat: Unable to find metadata for
>   table:index-3--243586308771972589 Index: {name: *id*, ns:
>   admin.system.version} - version too new for this mongod. See
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.4-index-downgrade for detailed
>   instructions on how to handle this error

Index meta information "says" that it's version is beyond >3.4, what of course it cannot be. Problem index is index of _id at admin.system.version -collection. We can "loose" this collection without problems because we know exactly what we have there. It would be easy, if you had enabled 'directoryPerDB' and especially 'directoryPerIndexes'.. BUT there is tool [to fix things in wiredTiger](http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.7.0/command_line.html), what I have never used but [here is story how to do it](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/). Find out files of admin.system.version -collection, rename those files and try to start mongod again.